# ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django

ModelForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(ChapterCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Not working
I wanna add `self.field` other. But it not working.

This is my code:

```py
class ChapterCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        exclude = ('user', 'book',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ChapterCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if Chapter.objects.filter(user=self.user, title=title).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('THIS CHAPTER ALREADY WRITTEN')
        return title
```

But this form it's working:

```py
class BookCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ('user',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(BookCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if Book.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
            if Book.objects.filter(user=self.user, title=title).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('YOU WROTE THIS BOOK ')
            raise forms.ValidationError('THIS BOOK ALREADY WRITTEN')
        return title
```

Please help me. Thanks so much

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Show what you try

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting and error?

Comment: [1]: https://imgur.com/E63Eyts
[2]: https://imgur.com/k0ZzXuI
[3]: https://imgur.com/mLSqh3Y
[4]: https://imgur.com/8kfja0X
[5]: https://imgur.com/VXOVwts
[6]: https://imgur.com/HAaNAmT
[7]: https://imgur.com/92ackF9
[8]: https://imgur.com/m3FWbC1
[9]: https://imgur.com/7iKQMeK

Comment: This is all my code in pictures.

Comment: Please don't add pictures of your errors/code. It helps if you paste it into your question

Comment: Sr i done try to paste picture code at topic but only can add a picture

Comment: You're not adding "user' to the form when initialising it. This needs to be done in the `get_form_kwargs` method of your class based view

Comment: In `BookCreateForm`:
        `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
            super(BookCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`  working with `self.user = kwargs.pop('user').
But it's not working in `ChapterCreateForm` and response for me Exception "KeyError" value is 'user'. I really don't know why it return exceptions

Comment: Thanks you so much Iain Shelvington. I really fixed it.

Comment: The issue is in your UserCreateChapterView, it's nothing to do with your Book form/view

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: @Hoàng Nguyễn If the solution worked for you, kindly upvote Iain Shelvington's suggestion or mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Amit that only works for answers. It does not work for comments

Comment: @Amit Sr this is first time i use stackoverfly so i really don't know how to good use it

Comment: No issues. People are here to help each other. Just to the left of the comments there is a grey triangle (upwars looking). If you hover it will become active. Then you can click on it. I am sure if you hover you will also see a tick mark getting activated. Hope it helps. All the best

Comment: @Amit Sr but i really can't find a grey triangle (upwars looking). But i was ticked star in my post. hope that will help.

Comment: Stevy said "that only works for answers. It does not work for comments". So as an example I have upvoted that comment. You should be able to see a 1 score there. May be the available choices are different for responders/readers on one hand and the member who actually posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `user` in the form kwargs by overriding `get_form_kwargs` in the class `UserCreateChapterView` as below:

```
class UserCreateChapterView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    ...
    ...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UserCreateChapterView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Now you can use `kwargs.pop('user')` in the `__init__` method of `ChapterCreateForm` and it should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: HoàngNguyễn please accept it as correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Maybe too late. But Thanks you @Animesh Kumar

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn not too late!